# PHP Duplicate records when checking if data was added successfully to mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm creating a simple new user signup form.
I've finally got it to add the new user data to the database.
However, i want to include a bit of php that automatically checks if this was successful. I've looked around and it seems to suggest this:

```
    $sql= "INSERT INTO users(Firstname, Lastname, username, password)
    VALUES ('$newfirstname', '$newlastname', '$newusername', '$newpassword')";

    mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            } 

    //if it works 
    echo "record added";



    mysqli_close($con);
```

However, this seems to add 2 duplicate records to the database! Can anyone see why?
I've isolated the problem to the

```
    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
        {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            }
```

Thanks for any help! Just getting started on PHP and mysql etc.

Comment: you are getting duplicate record because you are executing `mysqli_query($con, $sql);` twice. also add some unique constraints on the table.

Comment: thanks! Now i feel stupid looking back. Unique constraints are like an id number, yes? If so this is added on the actual database as am using phpMyadmin to autoincrement an id number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing your query twice, that's why you have double records, simply change to this

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    echo "record added";
} 
else
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
```